# syntax check. group two if statements

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
if [ $DISTRO = "REDHAT"] || [ $DISTRO = "FEDORA"]; then 
    if ! rpm -qa | grep -q glibc-static; then
        $BIN_ECHO -e " Package [glibc-static] not found. Installing.. "
        yum install glibc-static
    elif
        $BIN_ECHO -e " All required packages installed.. "
    fi
elif [ $DISTRO = "DEBIAN"]; then 
    if ! dpkg-query -l glibc; then
        $BIN_ECHO -e " Package [glibc] not found. Installing.. "
        apt-get install glibc
    elif
        $BIN_ECHO -e " All required packages installed.. "
    fi
fi
```

line 156: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

How do I put the two statements together?

Comment: Your source snippet doesn't have line numbers, so in the future, make sure there is a way for us to associate the error message with the line that generates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have a space before the final `]` on each test.

For example:

```
if [ $DISTRO = "REDHAT"] || [ $DISTRO = "FEDORA"]; then
```

must be re-written as either:

```
 if [ "$DISTRO" = REDHAT ] || [ "$DISTRO" = FEDORA ]; then
```

or

```
if test "$DISTRO" = REDHAT || test "$DISTRO" = FEDORA; then
```

Also note that there is no reason to quote literal strings, but you should quote variables.

You can also do :

```
if test "$DISTRO" = REDHAT -o "$DISTRO" = FEDORA; then
```

or

```
case "$DISTRO" in
REDHAT|FEDORA) ... ;;
DEBIAN) ... ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks. I found my issue but I also changed to the CASE statement way.